# How get two persons notified of a YouTube comment?

Tags: youtube

Suppose that someone (= *Person A*) posts a YouTube video comment, and the author of the video (= *Author*) replies. Graphically:

```
[YouTube video]
* top-level comment by Person A
  |
  * reply to Person A by Author
```

How can I (= *Person B*) reply to *Person A* so that both *Person A* and *Author* are notified of my comment?

I have understood that:

1. If I reply to *Person A*'s top-level comment, *Person A* will be notified of my reply, but *Author* won't.
2. If I reply to *Author*'s reply, *Author* will be notified of my reply, but *Person A* won't.